# Save data on database after click on place order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

What's wrong with my code? I can't even place an order or save it on database. I'm using ajax/jquery, it reaches the success but the problem is, it doesn't save in database.

PS: I also included place_order(); under script type.

Button:

```
<button id="place_order" class="btn btn-black">PLACE ORDER</button>
```

Jquery:

```
//Placing Order / Complete the Transaction
function place_order() {
    $('#place_order').click(function(e){
        var place_order = $('#place_order').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../pages/class.php',
            data: {place_order:place_order},
            success:function(data) {
                location.href="../pages/index.php";
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Class.php

```
if(isset($_POST['place_order'])) {
     if(isset($_SESSION['item_cart'])) {
          foreach($_SESSION['item_cart'] as $id=>$val) {
              $user_id = $_SESSION['id']; //id of users
              $product_stocks = $val['product_stocks']; //product stocks
              $product_id = $val['product_id']; //id of product/item                         
              $product_name = $val['product_name']; //name of product
              $product_quantity = $val['product_qty']; //quantity of product
              $product_price  = $val['product_price']; //price of product
              $product_size = $val['product_size']; //size of product
              //Total Price
              $total = $product_quantity * $product_price;

              //Check if the stocks is less than quantity
              if ($product_stocks < $product_quantity) {
                   echo "Insufficient Stock";
              } else {
                  //Insert it on database
                  $insert_query = "INSERT INTO tbltransactions(product_name, product_price, product_qty, total_price, product_id, account_id) VALUES('$product_name', $product_price, $product_quantity, $total, $product_id, $user_id)";
                  $query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $insert_query);
                  //If the query is success, update the stocks in database        
                  if($query) {
                      $update_query = "UPDATE tblproduct_extension SET product_stocks = $product_stocks - $product_quantity WHERE product_id = '$product_id' AND product_size='$product_size'";
                      $query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $update_query);
                      //unset the SESSION
                      unset($_SESSION['item_cart']);
                  }
              }   
          }   
      }   
  }
```

[image: transac]

Comment: is there any error coming up? either in console or any php/mysql error?

Comment: No errors in php/mysql. But I don't know on how to check errors in console.

Comment: right click->inspect in any browser, learn about developer console, google it

Comment: No errors in console log.

Comment: I've checked it on Network (Google developer) the Form Data is only, place_order=

Comment: that means your form data is not being sent, google `form serialization` using jquery. or in the data payload (data variable in the ajax call) you should mention all the individual variables seperatly.

Comment: But the button isn't using a form.

Comment: @Yeezus have you add `session_start()` at beginning of file?

Comment: Yes, I added session_start().

Comment: Is there's something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no value assigned to the variable place_order

```
     data: {place_order:place_order},
```

Assign value to variable using

```
    var place_order = $("#place_order").val(); //change field name
```

Comment: Done. Check it.

Comment: What value should I assign?

Comment: if you don't want to pass value to server remove data `data: {place_order:place_order},` and remove `if(isset($_POST['place_order'])) { }`

Comment: or change `var place_order = $('#place_order').val();` to  `var place_order = 1;`